# How Visual Studio Code formatting works out of the box on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, clang-format

I am running **vscode** on **osx** and have installed the [C/C++ plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools), which brought with it the `ClangFormat` package:

> Installing package 'C/C++ language components (OS X)'
>   **Installing package 'ClangFormat (OS X)'**
>   Installing package 'Mono Framework Assemblies'
>   Installing package 'Mono Runtime (OS X)'
>   Installing package 'LLDB 3.8.0 (OS X)'

I am able to format C++ code and even changed the `clang-format` style successfully:

> "C_Cpp.clang_format_style": "google"`

The thing is that I don't have [clang-format](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html) installed on my system and the path in vscode settings is not set either:

> "C_Cpp.clang_format_path": null

How is the formatting actually done here? What is this `ClangFormat` package that vscode installed? From where and where is it? It's not a plugin.
Does it use some package manager other than `homebrew` to install a distribution of `clang-format` in a custom location that is not in the path?

Comment: Are you sure that it is working? Even with properly set up clang-format c++ code formatting is typically hardly useful.

Comment: Yes, it is working and formatting according to the style I specify.
Why do you say it's hardly useful? I have it setup on linux also (with clang-format absolute path and my desired style) and works great.Works also on osx, but not sure how.

Comment: It turns out that vscode tries to install that **ClangPackage** together with the _C/C++ plugin_ also on linux, and on some version it works same as on osx (e.g. linux **mint**), as opposed to my **arch** linux setup where I need to manually install clang-format and give the absolute path.  
So I guess the question now applies also for linux **mint**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my Linux **Mint** indeed it's installed together with the C/C++ extension of Microsoft, alas it's installed locally within the module. It can be found here:

```
~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.12.3/LLVM/bin/
```

In **Windows**, similarly it can be found here:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode.cpptools-0.12.3\LLVM\bin\
```

In **OSX** is here:

```
~/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode.cpptools-0.12.3/LLVM/bin/
```

Not sure what could be wrong with **Arch**.

Comment: Actually, as per [VS Code extension documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_common-questions), in Mac you should be able to find all the extensions here: `~/.vscode/extensions`, I'd expect clang-format to be installed in the same location as in my Linux Mint mentioned above

Comment: Yes, I found the location also lof osx and update your answer. The remaining question is who maintains these builds of **clang-format** for each platform.

Comment: I would expect the C/C++ extension to bring in the latest (probably stable) release of clang-format with each version update. I still wonder though why it is not working for your arch. Can you check the file permissions?

Comment: It looks like it gets deployed in the same path also on **Arch**. In my case it was failing to run due to missing **libtinfo.so.5** dependency. After installing [libtinfo5](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/libtinfo5/) it works fine. So the **vscode** deployed version has this extra dependency.